# What happens to people outside Earth on the second coming?

Tags: bible

When Jesus returns, or the rapture,etc, and we having the events surrounding it, the bible says the whole earth will see it, day or night. Does the bible mention what happens to humans not on Earth, from space stations to the Moon and Mars (as current plans want to see humans on the Moon and on Mars before 2050.

Reference: [Luke 31:35](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Luke%2021:35) (ESV) "For it will come upon all who dwell on the face of the whole earth."

Comment: Assumiing we actually make it to life in space?

Comment: @james we've been to the moon in 1969, and the commercialisation of space is just starting, and we always have a crew on the ISS, the first commercial spaceport is being constructed and cost of visiting space will be less than 1 million USD by the end of the decade, compared to the 20 million or so it costs previously, it seems things are headed that way.

Comment: And why else would God create these other places to visit if we weren't meant to, using an agreement I disagree with myself; it's like why did God forbid eve from eating the apple (Or whatever the thing was) of she wasnt meant to

Comment: All I meant to point out it that it is a long way off. we don't have anyone on a distant planet yet. Who knows the second coming could be tomorrow or in 50 years.

Comment: Using this reasoning, we could ask "What about people who are underground?" or "What about blind people?".  I don't really see this as constructive.

Comment: @Richard, those people are still on earth. And blind people can still see God. The bible says everyone on Earth, including underground or whatever, it does not say everyone everywhere. Everything in the bible has centred around Earth, So you comment is not constructive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't worry you aren't going too miss it even if you are on Mars! "The whole earth" here refers to all of creation. The one who created those places is hardly going to forget to check for inhabitants. He knows the hairs on our head by number and every star by name.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I think I'll defer to you what you want to do about it. I think it can be labeled as a basic bible question (what does the bible say about ...), but I'm not sure if it should remain open.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to what previous posters have said, the Bible was written in a cultural and historical context where the concept of life outside our world wouldn't have been understood. Speaking about this would have caused confusion.

However, what we can do is apply what the Bible says to our situation. It follows from Psalm 139:8

> "If I go up to the heavens, you are there; if I make my bed in the
>   depths, you are there"

that wherever we are God is always there, and always aware of us.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at these two verses:

> 30 And then shall appear the sign of the Son of man in heaven: and then
>   shall all the tribes of the earth mourn, and they shall see the Son of
>   man coming in the clouds of heaven with power and great glory.
>   31 And he
>   shall send his angels with a great sound of a trumpet, and they shall
>   gather together his elect from the four winds, **from one end of heaven
>   to the other**. (Matthew 24:30-31; KJV)

And also see the Amplified translation:

> 30 Then the sign of the Son of Man will appear in the sky, and then
>   all the tribes of the earth will mourn and beat their breasts and
>   lament in anguish, and they will see the Son of Man coming on the
>   clouds of heaven with power and great glory [in brilliancy and
>   splendor].
>   31 And He will send out His angels with a loud trumpet
>   call, and they will gather His elect (His chosen ones) from the four
>   winds, [even] **from one end of the universe to the other**. (Matthew
>   24:30-31; Amplified)